# No Mouse During Windows 7 Install

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, keyboard, mouse, dell-xps

I'm having a problem installing Windows 7 on my Dell XPS m1330 notebook.  When booting from DVD I get to the screen where you select the language; time and currency; and keyboard input or method only to have no ability to enter them since then there is no keyboard or mouse control.

About the machine:
* Came from Dell with Ubuntu
* Working Ubuntu 9.04 install on one partiton
* No problem installing XP
* Same problem when attemping Vista install
* Latest version of BIOS installed

I have been banging my head against this for awhile now.  Open to any/all suggestions.

### UPDATE

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/105385/bsod-during-windows-7-install) is what happened when I tried installing from within XP

Comment: Are you using PS2 Mouse/keyboard or both are USB

Comment: not sure about this particular model, but check the BIOS options for something like 'USB Emulation' and enable it.

Comment: Laptop... Can you try with a USB keyboard? USB mouse? It's kinda weird that the laptop's keyboard and mouse pad aren't working during the install

Comment: @r0ca have tried with USB mouse with no avail

Comment: @Molly USB Emulation is already enabled

Comment: @matheeeny - turn it off and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an automated installer using a tool like [vLite](http://www.vlite.net/). You can put in all your info and get into windows without having to do more then boot to the CD. Look at a tutorial here:

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-unattended-windows-7-installation-setup/

The most likely reason you have this problem is that the chipset driver database the disk has doesn't have the driver for your computer. I've run into this a few times with windows XP and I had to slipstream a driver into the package to make it work. You may not need to do that if they have the network driver. Windows 7 can contact microsoft and get updated drivers once you get into the GUI.

[EDIT]

An alternate approach is to clear the drive completely. Either delete all partitions or write zero's to the drive by using a program like [killdisk](http://www.killdisk.com/downloadfree.htm). The purpose of this is to setup a blank drive for the windows 7 install. When I was reinstalling windows after a motherboard change, I had to start with an empty drive or windows couldn't use it to install.

Once you get the windows 7 system up and running, you can then resize the partitions using something like [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm). You can then install Ubuntu to the newly opened up space. I'm not a linux guy so I can't really help with that spot.

So assuming that you can get a properly slipsteamed disk, you should be able to get it dropped onto the system and make it work.

[/EDIT]

Comment: I couldn't get this approach to work.

Comment: What did it do? Any error messages? Did the process still drop to a screen that required mouse and KB input in a GUI mode?

Answer (score 0):

[A comment by matheeeny (the one asking this question) on a related issue](https://superuser.com/questions/105385/bsod-during-windows-7-install) may help:

1. Reset the BIOS to factory defaults
2. After resetting the BIOS, switch AHCI back to ATA (my BIOS forced me to toggle a secondary setting)

And then the install worked.

Prior to this rying to install Windows 7 on a Dell M1530 would not recognize the native keyboard/mouse, or USB keyboards and mice. It would get to the initial setup screen and I could not interact with the computer.  I toggled all the USB settings in the BIOS to no avail, and even switched AHCI to ATA (just in case).

Comment: Why switch to ancient IDE/ATA compatibility mode? It should not influence the mouse and AHCI has more features and is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue while helping my girlfriend build her gaming PC. We tried everything listed here, and what finally worked was completely disabling USB 2.0 and USB 3.0. It got the Win7 installer to use the PS/2 port. Go figure :/