# installing windows 7 without keyboard

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No Mouse During Windows 7 Install](https://superuser.com/questions/105263/no-mouse-during-windows-7-install)

Does anyone know if there is a way to install windows 7 without a keyboard and just a mouse?

Comment: Windows 7 has Tablet functionality built-in. The virtual keyboard should pop up relatively early. There is a chance that it works straight away, if you don't get blocked by the BIOS. Have you tried it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/105263/no-mouse-during-windows-7-install

Comment: Pekka: Not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess no except if you run the installation through a script which will answer all the question the installation will require to fill? computer name, language and so on....

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of google searches, I'm guessing no, you can't completely finish the install without the keyboard unless you use a script.  The biggest hangup is the activation code - most other text fields are optional or are auto-populated with defaults.

Comment: You do not need to supply a key or activation code on installation, with XP SP3 and Vista onwards.  You can leave it blank.

Comment: I've always put the key in during installation.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this all the time, especially with virtual machines and laptops.  You do not even need an optical drive in the machine either, which is useful when installing on netbooks.

You need Windows Server with the **Windows Deployment Services** role installed and the machine you are installing on needs to be able to **PXE network boot**.  You can also use the **Windows Automated Installation Kit** with SysPrep and WinPE to make customised unattended installations through it.

Comment: How do you propose the user sets PXE network boot as the first boot device without a keyboard?

Comment: @RichardHedges From my experience it seems to be in the default BIOS boot order, once nothing is found the HDDs or optical drives, but I have no idea why I answered this question with this answer.  I must have been shmoking something.

Comment: PXE network boot no doubt would be the answer, providing network boot is enabled. However if it's not, I suppose resetting CMOS could resolve that for the user if network boot is enabled by default.